# Changing the source data of Pivot table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How can I make the selection of source data dynamic. Meaning, if the data count increases/Decreases next month, the code automatically selects all the data.

```
Sub Macro7()
    Sheets("Summary Global").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "C:\Desktop\LEAD & LAG Report\LAG Data\2018\July\[LAG_July 2018 Report - Global - Copy.xls]DATA!R1C1:R1138C168" _
        , Version:=xlPivotTableVersion10)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("month of closure"). _
        CurrentPage = "aug. 2018"
End Sub
```

Comment: first, do you know ow to change the source data manually to get you desired result?

Comment: You can use a Named Range (either change it with VBA, or use `OFFSET` with `COUNTA` to make it dynamic), or use `Range.End` and `Range.Address` to work out what `SourceData` should be

Comment: I used COUNTA to make the range dynamic. I am new to excel and VBA so don't know much. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your range is fixed to a certain row.

you could change the reference of your sourcedata to C1:C168. in this way it goes all the way down.

another option is to use a namedrange and have the named range change everytime your data changes.
eg:

```
Call ThisWorkbook.Names.Add("rangeForPivot", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("rangeForPivot").UsedRange())
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. However I used the following code and it is running successfully: Source_Sheet.Activate
Set Startpoint = Source_Sheet.Range("A1")
LastCol = Startpoint.End(xlToRight).Column
DownCell = Startpoint.End(xlDown).Row
Set DataRange = Source_Sheet.Range(Startpoint, Cells(DownCell, LastCol))
NewRange = Source_Sheet.Name & "!" & DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Change Pivot Table Data Source Range Address

Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1"). _
ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRange)